# Log normal stock prices - Steps after Ito

Tags: stochastic-calculus

When we specify a GBM stock price:

$$dS =  \mu S dt + \sigma S dW$$

And then we change it to:
$$\frac{dS}{S} =  \mu dt + \sigma dW$$

The we assume: let $Z_t = f(S_t) = \log S_t$, where $f(x) = \log x$. Then by the Ito's formula, we have:

$$ Z_t - Z_0 = f(S_t) - f(S_0) = \int_{0}^{t} f'(S_s) \; dS_s + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{2} f''(S_s) \; dS_s^2,$$

What happened to $\frac{\partial Z_t}{\partial t} $ in Ito ? Ito gives:
$$ dZ_t = \frac{\partial Z_t}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial Z_t}{\partial S}dS + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Z_t}{\partial S^2}dS^2$$

and somehow we assumed that this quantity $\frac{\partial Z_t}{\partial t} $ is null.

[See demonstration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126870/whats-the-solution-of-stock-price-based-on-gbm-model)

Comment: Well $Z$ is only a function of stock price $S$. The t variation comes back via the quadratic variance of $ds^2$.

Comment: You do not have to take in account the fact that S is a function of t ? I feel a bit stupid now :)

Comment: No worries. When I came across this, i asked this very question to myself also.